# Tomcat error while running spring mvc web application

Tags: spring, tomcat

Actually i am running spring mvc web application on tomcat server using eclipse but while  starting a tomcat i am getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML       document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]
```

I am using following xml configuration  files

1. Web.xml

   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   ```
   <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
       </servlet-class>

       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

2.HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</bean
```

Comment: post your web.xml and the full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Spring by default, looks for a file at */WEB-INF/your-servlet-name-servlet.xml*, if exclusively not specified in *init-param* attribute with name as "contextConfigLocation". 
That means it takes the value of the  element and appends -servlet.xml to it and looks for it in WEB-INF.

For example:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Here Spring picks up web-application-config.xml file under WEB-INF folder as this was exclusively specified. If this is not specified, it will look for /WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml   as "HelloWeb" is the servlet name.

So make sure you have this file in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Hi Sir, I used contextConfigLocation but while starting tomacat in eclipse it is showing this error. I used the configuration mentioned by you but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.io.FileNotFoundException` says that it couldn't open `/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml`.
This is typical when the location is wrong and the file doesn't exist there. Please check if the filename is correct. Also try removing slash '`/`' at the beginning.

**EDIT:**
If the file is referenced from the same location, you may also try to type only `HelloWeb-servlet.xml` without directory.

Comment: Hi Sir i am new to spring mvc . i am using the following xml files

Comment: Hi Sir, Actually i am new to spring i provided the xml files above please guide me for those files

Comment: Where is HelloWeb-servlet.xml referenced (defined)?

Comment: Sir can you give some example for this

Comment: Where do you have in your whole project a String 'HelloWeb-servlet.xml' ? Look in all XML files. Then try to adjusting the path as I mentioned in the answer.